# Taking variables outside of query in sql

Tags: sql

I know my title is a bit misleading but i am unsure of what would be a good title.

Authored has 2 columns namely ID, PubID

Is there anyway i could output the P into my result.

I would like to know for each respective ID, PubID pair, how many rows would have the same PubID but different ID.

```
select a.authorId, P 
from Authored A 
WHERE 1 < 

(Select count(*) as P
from Authored B
where A.pubId = B.pubId
AND A.authorId<> B.authorId)
```

Thanks to all who have answered.

---

### Table

```
AuthorID       pubID
1                2
3                2
4                2
10               1
11               1
```

---

### Expected Result

```
AuthorID     NumberOfOccurenceOfDiffAuthIDWithSamePubID
1                       3
3                       3
4                       3
10                      2
11                      2
```

Comment: Can you show some data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated using `count() over()`:

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/156b3/8)**:

```
select a.AuthorId, count(*) over(partition by pubId) counts
from Authored a 
order by a.AuthorId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for MS Sql server:

```
select 
    *, 
    COUNT(*) over (partition by pubId) 
From Authored  
where authorId<>pubId
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean, its not clear what you are asking? [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/906ea/3).

```
select
    count(ID) P,
    PubID
from
    (select distinct ID, pubID from Authored) d
group by
    PubID
```

---

```
This will give you the number of distinct `ID/authorId` for each `PubID\pubId`
```